# Loading activity indicator for display during async request

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have been trying to implement code that will display a activity indicator in a sub view during a request. It's meant to be used for loading, however it never displays yet if I go to another segue and then return back the indicator is now there. This makes me believe the superview doesn't get reloaded until my function has run by which time the sub view doesn't need to be displayed

Example:

loadingIndicator.startIndicator(self.view)

```
        let parameters = Parameters()

        parameters.addParams(search: search)
        let request = SearchRQ(parameters: parameters)

        request.getResponse()

        while !request.isComplete
        {
            //Wait
        }

        let results = request.parseResponse()
        self.results = results

        loadingIndicator.stopIndicator(self.view)

        performSegueWithIdentifier("showSearchResults", sender: sender)
```

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As matt stated, you need to add your activity indicator to the view (or any UI changes for that matter) on the main thread.

You can do that like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
})
```

To move waiting for your response OFF the main thread, change your getResponse function so that it has a completion handler. :

```
func getResponse(responseReceived:() ->Void) {
    // Once I get my response:
    responseReceived()
}
```

Then you can do the appropriate changes after you've received the response.

```
getResponse {
    let results = request.parseResponse()
    self.results = results

    loadingIndicator.stopIndicator(self.view)

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showSearchResults", sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't appear to work, if you see my code above maybe that'll help to explain

Comment: Ah, I think you are blocking the main thread in the  while !request.isComplete block. Your app will essentially be frozen until then.

Comment: Right, is there anyway to get around this. Sorry if a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

You need to step onto the *main thread* in order to display and start the activity indicator, and then step *off* the main thread to do your asynchronous activity.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? :)

Comment: Try searching on Stack Overflow. There are _lots_ of examples.

Comment: Ok I'll see if I can find it

Answer (score 0):

In the end the following code worked and allowed to show/hide

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { () -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                //Display my activity indicator
            })

            //Create XML Request, Parse Response

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                //Hide activity indicator
                //Perform Segue
            })


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Swift 5, you can use the following simple extension:

```swift
// Activity Indicator Extension
var vSpinner : [UIView] = []

extension UIViewController {
    func showSpinner(onView : UIView) {
        let spinnerView = UIView.init(frame: onView.bounds)
//        spinnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, alpha: 0.9)
        let ai = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(style: .medium)
        ai.startAnimating()
        ai.center = spinnerView.center
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinnerView.addSubview(ai)
            onView.addSubview(spinnerView)
        }
        
        vSpinner.append(spinnerView)
    }
    
    func removeSpinner() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            vSpinner.popLast()?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Within your async task use these two handy boys:

`showSpinner(onView: self.view)` Remember to replace *self.view* with any kind of view you desire

`self.removeSpinner()` Remove the loading indicator: